# Find optimum diagonal matrix $D$ to maximize $ADB$ above a threshold $\gamma$

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, linear-programming, linear-transformations, nonlinear-optimization

I have a problem to find the optimum diagonal matrix $D$, which would maximizes the number of elements in $ADB$ which are above a certain positive number $\gamma$.

In other words, the problem is stated as follows,

\begin{align}
& \max_D  \mathrm{sum}(ADB \geq \gamma) \\
& D \in R_+^{n \times n} \text{ is a positive diagonal matrix} \\
& A \in R^{n \times n} \text{ is a symmetric Z-matrix} \\
& B \in R_+^{n \times n} \text{ is a symmetric positive matrix}
\end{align}

Z-matrix is a matrix with all non-diagonal entries being nonpositive.

Can anyone help me please?